# upgrade MySQL through apt not effect?

Tags: apt, mysql

I am upgrading `mysql-server` and `mysql-client` my 12.04 using `apt-get`.
seems the upgrade didn't take effect?
Any thoughts why this happen? I did reboot after upgrade. Thanks.

```
$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.22, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
$ mysqld -V
mysqld  Ver 5.5.22-0ubuntu1 for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))


$ sudo apt-cache policy mysql-server
[sudo] password for dli: 
mysql-server:
  Installed: 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
  Candidate: 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 0
        500 http://os.cgs.wustl.edu/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://os.cgs.wustl.edu/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.22-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://os.cgs.wustl.edu/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages


$ sudo apt-cache policy mysql-client
mysql-client:
  Installed: 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
  Candidate: 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 0
        500 http://os.cgs.wustl.edu/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://os.cgs.wustl.edu/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.22-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://os.cgs.wustl.edu/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: mysql-server and mysql-client are meta packages. You should check the installed versions of mysql-client-5.5 and mysql-server-5.5.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I tried `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5` instead, it works, solved my problem. Does anyone could turn the comment above to an answer? Then I could accept it :)

Comment: seems the mysql client still showing the old version, `$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.22, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2`, while policy shows the new version, `$ sudo apt-cache policy mysql-client
mysql-client:
  Installed: 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
`

Comment: @dli what's the result of `apt-cache policy mysql-client-5.5`?

Comment: yes, it's `Installed: 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As SpamapS said in comments, `mysql-server` and `mysql-client` are meta packages. This *meta packages* are empty and normally depends of packages that can change name regularly with version changes, or a large amount of packages that do the same function (ie `ubuntu-desktop`). As you can see:

```
braiam@bt:~$ apt-cache depends mysql-client
mysql-client
  Depends: mysql-client-5.5
braiam@bt:~$ apt-cache depends mysql-server
mysql-server
  Depends: mysql-server-5.5
```

Both packages depends of others, so you must check those to see the actual version apt is installing:

```
braiam@bt:~$ apt-cache policy mysql-server-5.5 | grep Installed
  Installed: 5.5.31+dfsg-1
braiam@bt:~$ apt-cache policy mysql-client-5.5 | grep Installed
  Installed: 5.5.31+dfsg-1
```

You should run `apt-cache policy mysql-server-5.5 mysql-client-5.5 | grep Installed` to check out the installed version on your system.